# How to merge 2 tables with user and timestamp in python

Tags: python, time, lookup

I need to merge 2 tables of millions of records. The common fields are user and timestamp. The problem is that the timestamp is different in both tables, so I need to create a new variable or establish a range of 5 seconds to find a perfect coincidence between tables 1 and 2.

I am trying to use lookup or function y.  I am not an expert, so I really need your help.

I know that it seems easy for an expert. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Some sample data from each would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest pandas `merge_asof` function:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

I believe the argument `direction='nearest'` might solve your problem.

Comment: Richard, thank you very much for your kind help. My problem is a little more complicated. Can I have maybe your e-mail to discuss a little further? Thank you very much.